# Would a Javascript Function Return Anything if Javascript is Disabed in the Browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to know what will happen if I write a javascript which validates on a button click event. If I have disabled javascript in my browser, what will my javascript function return?

Comment: If JS is disabled, then obviously nothing will happen with the function. But it really shouldn't matter since your validation will ultimately take place on  the server, not the client. At least I hope you're validating on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing will happen if javascript is disabled.  Even `<script>` tags are totally ignored

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off javascript, then `<script>` tag will be ignored, and in reverse, the `<noscript>` tag will not ignored when javascript is disabled, so it is used as:

```
<noscript>
You need to turn on javascript.
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<noscript>` tag. That will be displayed when JavaScript is disabled. Otherwise anything thing inside `<script>` will be completely ignored.

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp